# Rails: Output a form field name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way in Rails to output a field name that would normally by output by a form helper (e.g. `f.text_field`).
I'd like to output the field name (e.g. `person[first_name]`) and pass it to a partial.

`<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
       First name: <%= person_form.text_field :first_name %>
       ....`

Would output an text input with `name="person[first_name]"` property. Instead out outputting the text input element, I'm looking for a way to create (via Rails) that text output: `person[first_name]` and pass it to a partial.

pseudo code:
`render partial: 'my_custom_element', locals: { field_name: generate_field_name(@person, :name)}`

Comment: thanks a lot. Could you give us more information. The problem is not clear to me

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: sorry ... maybe I don't understand or I don't know how to do this